# Angular Binding on checkbox not working on model

Tags: angular

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items" (click)="ModifyItem(item)" class="mask flex-center rgba-blue-light">
  <td>{{ item.price}}</td>
  <td>{{ item.make}}</td>
  <td>{{ item.type}}</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox"   name="isSelected" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" [checked]="item.isSelected" ngDefaultControl [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

the checkbox value is not changing when checking the box. im relatively new to angular and so am stuck with getting the isSelected to bind properly. keeps displaying false which is the default value of model

```
export class FetchDataComponent {
  items: Items[];
  public item: Item= new Item(null,[],null,false);

 
  eventsSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  editing: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  selected: Subject<Item> = new Subject<Item>();

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string ) {
    http.get<Item[]>(baseUrl + 'game').subscribe(result => {

      this.items= result;

    }, error => console.error(error));

  }

  public AddItem()
  {  
      this.eventsSubject.next();  
  }

  public ModifyItem(item: Game) {
   
    this.game = item;
   
    this.editing.next(true);
    this.selected.next(item);

  }
```

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: when you console log your get request response what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

depending on what is inside `(click)="ModifyItem(Item)`
but I think this modifies the item and cancel the click event of the checkbox

without knowing what is inside this function it is hard to tell what exactly is done.

here is a working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-txoahc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Im already using ngModel on the checkbox the click event is for the table row

Comment: @user2122032 yes but can you put in your post what ModifyItem does please?

Comment: well as you can see im iterating over a list of items which is creating is row. each row is bound to an "item" object. When i click on a row the modifyItem method recieves an item object as arguement

Comment: @user2122032 yes but you send `Item` and not `item` also my question is what is exactly inside your function. thanks in advance.

Comment: typo it should be item

Comment: My question is concerning the checkbox not the rest of the code

Comment: @user2122032 yes but what I am saying is that your function `ModifyItem` may be the cause of your problem. I've made a stackblitz with pretty much the same things you have made with no problems have you checked it ou?

Comment: I was unable to load the stackblitz

Comment: @user2122032 I've changed the link please try again.

Comment: @user2122032 so you can see the same problem on the stackblitz?

Comment: I will add some detail

Answer (score 0):

1.-Remove the [checked] and [ngModelOptions]
-`[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"`is used if you has a input using [(ngModel)] inside a FormGroup

2.-In (click) you forget item.isSelect=!item.isSelect

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items" 
      (click)="item.isSelect=!item.isSelect;ModifyItem(item)">

//or add in your function
ModifyItem(item: Game){
     item.isSelect=!item.isSelect
      ...rest of your code...
}
```

3.- For me is strange you use Subjects and I don't know the aim of this. Generally you use a Subject in a service so, one or more component subscribe to this subject received the change. If you want comunicate Two components are at time in the app principal you can use a template reference variable